# ruby metaprogramming - getting method names and parameter info for a class

Tags: ruby, class, methods, metaprogramming

I want to get class methods in an object. Please see the following example
    I have a class "user.rb"

```
class User
  def say_name

  end

  def walk(p1)

  end

  def run(p1, p2)

  end
end
```

and I wrote the following code

```
require 'user.rb'

a = User.new

arr = a.public_methods(all = false)
```

Above code will return the method name, But my question is I want to get the method name with parameters

```
def def run(p1, p2)

end
```

I want to get the method name ("run") and its parameter names (p1, p2) or parameter count (2)

can someone help me, thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
User.new.method(:run).arity   # => 2
```

Comment: or, if you dont want to create an instance: `User.instance_method(:run).arity #=> 2`

Answer (score 1):

if you want parameters then http://github.com/rdp/arguments is your friend

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
User.new.method(:run).parameters # => [[:req, :p1], [:req, :p2]]
```

`req` means it's a required field. Other values you might get are:

- `def run(p1 = nil)` => `[[:opt, :p1]]`
- `def run(*p1)` => `[[:rest, :p1]]`
- `def run(&p1)` => `[[:block, :p1]]`
- `def run(p1:)` => `[[:key, :p1]]`
- `def run(p1: nil)` => `[[:keyopt, :p1]]`
- `def run(**p1)` => `[[:keyrest, :p1]]`